# Having issues with replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

Maybe I am using replaceAll incorrectly, but I am unable to find why it acts this way. I want to simply remove a $ sign from a string and then output the string.

```
public class Example{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "$50";
    s.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

However, this still outputs the $ symbol with the string. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of `replaceAll` to a variable:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

because a `String` object is immutable.